# How tf-idf is relevant in calculating sentence vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am interested to find sentence vectors using word vectors.I  read that by multiplying each word's tf-idf weights with their vectors and finding their average we can get whole sentence vector.

Now I want to know that how these tf-idf weights helps us to get sentence vectors i.e how these tf-idf and sentence vector are related?

Comment: `tf*idf` of a word is a weight for word , sentences are contains some words, so a sentence will be a vector of some weights , this is the sentence vector.

Answer (score 0):

Any aggregative operation on the word vectors can give you a sentence vector.
You should consider what do you want your representation to ***mean*** and choose the operation accordingly.

Possible operations are summing the vectors, averaging them, concatenating, etc.